# Order date and specially time in decreasing order

Tags: r

I have a dataset in the format

```
2037-12-31 06:30:06
```

and I have tried to sort it in a decreasing format 
I have tried
Let dataset name is `dataset` and column `Timestamp`
I have tried

```
dataset[order(as.Date(dataset$Timestamp,format="%d%m%Y%H%M%s"),decreasing=TRUE),]
```

But its still not working

Answer (score 0):

First let's prepares some mock data:

```
text <- "Timestamp data1 data2
   '2037-12-31 06:30:06' 0.618 1.41
   '2037-12-31 07:30:20' 42  42
   '2016-01-08 19:15:00' 77 124
   '2035-10-09 08:05:01' 3.141 98" 
dataset <- read.table(text=text, header = TRUE)
```

Now the data is stored in a data.frame called `dataset`:

```
> dataset
            Timestamp  data1  data2
1 2037-12-31 06:30:06  0.618   1.41
2 2037-12-31 07:30:20 42.000  42.00
3 2016-01-08 19:15:00 77.000 124.00
4 2035-10-09 08:05:01  3.141  98.00
```

In order to rearrange the rows as a function of date and time, the values in the `Timestamp` column can be converted with `as.POSIXlt()`.

Then the data can be reordered in reverse chronological order:

```
> dataset[order(as.POSIXlt(dataset$Timestamp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s"),decreasing=TRUE),] 
#            Timestamp  data1  data2
#2 2037-12-31 07:30:20 42.000  42.00
#1 2037-12-31 06:30:06  0.618   1.41
#4 2035-10-09 08:05:01  3.141  98.00
#3 2016-01-08 19:15:00 77.000 124.00
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sir, I have 807055 obs of 10 variables, in which one column is of Date , I want to order them in decreasing order

Comment: You have used text , how can I use them in my code ?   I have a whole column of that

Comment: I needed a sample data set to demonstrate the principle, and for this I used `read.table()` combined with `text`. Your data is presumably already stored in a data.frame, so you can skip to the end of the code. The important part is here the use of `POSIXlt` and the precise form of the `format` specifier.